# Plotting a bar chart with seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am plotting the following values, using seaborn:

```
import pandas as pd
f = [0.31,0.75,0.75,0.75, 0.66,0.83,0.57, 0.69, 0.64,0.61, 0.81,0.21,0.71,0.71,0.64,0.55,0.72,0.74,0.73,0.77]
p = [0.53, 0.72,0.73,0.70,0.44,0.38,0.68,0.79,0.60,0.76, 0.76,0.32,0.84,0.79,0.80,0.38,0.77,0.86,0.81,0.79]
r = [0.74,0.54,0.63,0.61,0.41,0.83,0.63,0.67,0.63,0.53, 0.86,0.51,0.21,0.68,0.59,0.98,0.78,0.75,0.71,0.67]
a = [0.92,0.93,0.92,0.92,0.94,0.82,0.97,0.94,0.91,0.93, 0.97,0.91,0.94,0.93,0.94,0.71,0.93,0.91,0.85,0.94]
pp=['B','B','B','B','B','T','T','T','T','T','B','B','B','B','B','T','T','T','T','T']  
m=['N','L','S','G','Rt','N','L','S','G','Rt','N','L','S','G','Rt','N','L','S','G','Rt']
d=['yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no']

df = {'DD':d, 'PP': pp, 'M': m, 'P': p, 'R':r, 'F':f,'A':a}
df2= pd.DataFrame(data=df)
df2 = df.melt(['PP', 'M', 'D'])
```

The code for the plot is

```
g = sns.catplot(
    data=df2,
    x='m',
    y='value',
    hue='PP',
    col='variable',
    col_wrap=2,
    col_order = ['P', 'R', 'F', 'A'],
    kind='bar',
     ci=None,
    facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False},
height=8.)

d_col = df2['DD'][:8]
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
    for i,l in enumerate(labels):
        tmp = l.get_text()
        labels[i] = tmp + '\n' + d_col[i]
        ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
sns.set_style(style='white')
```

However the plot seems to be wrong. Also, I cannot see `no` values, but only `yes`. My expected output would be [image]

In the example for the plot I used dummy values for the bar chart. Each m should have both yes and no and this would be repeated for each subplot (left blank only for example purposes).

Can you please tell me how to generate a similar output? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating two bars for each 'M' (one for 'PP' being 'B' and one for 'T').  There are no bars separated per 'DD'. Seaborn only accepts one column for `hue`. You can combine  the 'PP' and 'DD' column to a new column and use that for `hue`, resulting in 4 bars for each 'M'.

Here is a code example. Also, `sns.catplot` seems to want `sharey` and `sharex` directly as keywords (at least in the current version 0.11.1).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

f = [0.31,0.75,0.75,0.75,0.66,0.83,0.57,0.69,0.64,0.61,0.81,0.21,0.71,0.71,0.64,0.55,0.72,0.74,0.73,0.77]
p = [0.53,0.72,0.73,0.70,0.44,0.38,0.68,0.79,0.60,0.76,0.76,0.32,0.84,0.79,0.80,0.38,0.77,0.86,0.81,0.79]
r = [0.74,0.54,0.63,0.61,0.41,0.83,0.63,0.67,0.63,0.53,0.86,0.51,0.21,0.68,0.59,0.98,0.78,0.75,0.71,0.67]
a = [0.92,0.93,0.92,0.92,0.94,0.82,0.97,0.94,0.91,0.93,0.97,0.91,0.94,0.93,0.94,0.71,0.93,0.91,0.85,0.94]
pp = ['B','B','B','B','B','T','T','T','T','T','B','B','B','B','B','T','T','T','T','T']
m = ['N','L','S','G','Rt','N','L','S','G','Rt','N','L','S','G','Rt','N','L','S','G','Rt']
d = ['yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no']

df = {'DD': d, 'PP': pp, 'M': m, 'P': p, 'R': r, 'F': f, 'A': a}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
df2 = df1.melt(['PP', 'M', 'DD'])
df2['PP_DD'] = df2['PP'] + ', ' + df2['DD']

sns.set_style(style='white')
g = sns.catplot(
    data=df2,
    x='M',
    y='value',
    hue='PP_DD',
    col='variable',
    col_wrap=2,
    col_order=['P', 'R', 'F', 'A'],
    kind='bar',
    ci=None,
    sharey=False, sharex=False,
    height=3, aspect=1.5)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.06, bottom=0.09)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot with two hues]

Comment: Thank you JohanC. Your answer shows a very smart solution!